# Setting a Google Form destination to it responses via google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to set up a script that creates a form based on a sheet (which works) then I want it to submit the responses to a specific sheet so I can have have scripts interact with it, manually connecting the forms to the sheet won't be practical as multiple form could be created every day

when I run the script this error code appears

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setDestination on object FormApp.Form.

below is my code, any help will be apricated

```
function bug() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('TC');
  var value = sheet.getRange("A3").getValue();
  var em = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var cos = sheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
  var name = sheet.getRange("D3").getValue();
  var sup = sheet.getRange("C3").getValue();

  var form = FormApp.create(value);
  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  item.setHelpText("Name: " + name +
                 "\n\nEmail: " + em +
                 "\n\nQuote No: " + value +
                 "\n\nProject: " + sup +
                 "\n\nTotal Cost: " + cos +
                 "\n\nBy selecting approve you agree to the cost and timeframe specified by the quote and that the details above are correct")
                 .setChoices([item.createChoice('Approve'), item.createChoice('Deny')]);
  var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
  item.setTitle('What extras would you like to add on?');
  item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Damp-Course'),
        item.createChoice('Wrap'),
        item.createChoice('Taco')
    ]);
  Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
  Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
  Logger.log('ID: ' + form.getId());

  var ssId = sheet.getSheetId();
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ssId);

  var SendTo = "insertgenertic@email.com";

  var link = form.getPublishedUrl();
  var message = "Please follow the link to accept you Quotation " + form.getPublishedUrl();

 //set subject line

 var Subject = 'Quote' + value + 'Confirmation';

  const  recipient = em;
  const subject = "Confirmation of order"
  const url = link

GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send form responses to a previously existing sheet. When you link your form to a destination spreadsheet, it will always create a new sheet to store those responses, no matter whether you use Apps Script to set the destination. You can only choose whether it will be an existing spreadsheet or a new one.

Because of this, you have to provide the spreadsheet id when calling [Form.setDestination(type, id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setdestinationtype,-id). Since you are providing the sheet id instead, you are getting an error.

You should do something like this:

```
function bug() {
  // ...
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, spreadsheetId);
  // ...
}
```

#### Related:

- [Link Google Form responses To Already Existing Google Spreadsheet Tab](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120385/link-google-form-responses-to-already-existing-google-spreadsheet-tab)
- [Choose where to save form responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en#zippy=%2Cchoose-where-to-store-responses)

Comment: thank you Lambichus and Cooper, I was hoping it was possible but I will just sent up a trigger script to move the info then after the sheet is created,   thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

`form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ssId);`

ssId is supposed to be the id of a Spreadsheet not a sheet

[example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type)

[spreadsheet id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getId())

[getSheetId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId())